# Translating column values in a view control

Tags: xpages

I have an application that uses a classic frontend for the Notes users and now has a XPages frontend for web users.

I've used the Localization feature for making the application multilangual. But this doesn't help me on translating column values in a view.

I've come up with a solution via text files which works well in non-categorized views.

I've created a text file for each supported language and linked them as a bundle ressource to the XPages. In the view column I used this code :

```
var cat = @ReplaceSubstring(rowData.getColumnValue("Category")," ","");
var catStr = String(cat);
return categories[catStr];
```

If I use the same method in a categorized column, I get an error :

> Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
>   Script interpreter error, row=1, column=5: unknown element '' in Java-class 'java.util.PropertyResourceBundle'

Does anyone know what this means ? Or are there better solutions for getting a view columns value localized ?

Comment: My fault.

Some documents displayed in the view had a blank value, so there was no match in the language files.

I didn't checked that before, because the flat sorted view was working. Seems like the categorized column really needs a value.

A simple check on empty string fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting approach. Since you categorize in a single language this will determine your sort order. How do users react when they see:

```
blue, yellow, green, red, black
```

instead of

```
black, blue, green, red, yellow
```

since your categories in the view would be

```
blau, gelb, gruen, rot, schwarz
```

Content internationalization is a tricky topic.

Comment: Yes, it is tricky. I'm still working on this topic because some other problems appeared after translation was running.

Comment: one though, raw haven't fully thought thru: if you do the lookup at save time and store the values with the language. It would make the view index larger but that might be worth it. something like
"de-schwarz":"en-black". Then a specialized custom control that takes a [tree-table](http://code.google.com/p/dojo-treetable/) to render your data, where you stop when you have exhausted the selected language

Answer (score 0):

You could do the translation in an xe:objectData control and return the objects for a datatable as a sorted list